# Hola quisiera hacer un API que me ejecute un comando dentro de mi MIKROTIK

Tags: php

Hola quisiera crear un API que me ejecute un comando dentro del mikrotik,lo que no se es como seria el fichero php para mandarle directo la ejecucion del comando al mikrotik que no encuentro por ningun lado seria esta /ip dhcp-client release 0. Este api que muestro cuando lo ejecuto desde el servidor web me aparece un error.

```
<?php

require('routeros_api.class.php');

$API = new routeros_api();

$API->debug = true;

if ($API->connect('192.168.17.135', 'api', 'api')) {

    $API->write('/system/script/run',false);
    $API->write("=.id=script5");


   $API->disconnect();

}

?>
```

El error seria este:

> Warning: require(routeros_api.class.php) [function.require]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\usbwebserver\root\api\routeros_api.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   'routeros_api.class.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in
>   D:\usbwebserver\root\api\routeros_api.php on line 3.

Por favor si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado vaga... ¿Tienes un servidor web que soporta php dentro del MIKROTIK?

Comment: utilizo como servidor web usbwebserver v8 pero tengo tambien el wampp y el xampp tengo ya una idea de como funciona el api pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me da un error que seria este :

Comment: Warning: require(routeros_api.class.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\usbwebserver\root\api\routeros_api.php on line 3

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'routeros_api.class.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\usbwebserver\root\api\routeros_api.php on line 3

Comment: El api es este  <?php

require('routeros_api.class.php');

$API = new routeros_api();

$API->debug = true;

if ($API->connect('192.168.17.135', 'api', 'api')) {

 $API->write('/system/script/run',false);
 $API->write("=.id=script5");


   $API->disconnect();

}

?>

Comment: El problema es que no está encontrando este archivo en tu web root: `routeros_api.class.php`. Debes colocar el archivo en el mismo directorio que  `routeros_api.php` o hacer require con la ruta absoluta del archivo (no recomendado)

Comment: Esos dos php se encuentran ubicados en la misma carpeta pero es como si le faltara alguna libreria ssh o algun componente ssh al servidor web o a windows

Comment: No, el error es claro e inconfundible `No such file or directory`, si fuera error de librería el error sería distinto. Recomiendo revisar la configuración de PHP para asegurar que si se permite include y require, también puedes usar la función `getcwd()` para saber que estas en el directorio de trabajo correcto cuando haces el `include`.

Comment: Ya di con el error ya se conecta al mikrotik el problema ahora es que no ejecuta el comando

Comment: Para eso puede haber algunas razones, como que el usuario que está intentando ejecutar ese comando no tenga suficientes permisos para ejecutarlo. ¿Con qué usuario  está corriendo el servidor web? La función `get_current_user();` te puede ayudar con ello

Comment: intente con dos usuarios uno que tiene permiso para write, read y api e intente con otro que tiene todos los permisos osea full

Comment: ¿Y si se conecta con el Mikrotik? veo que tienes debug enabled, debería decirte si se conecta y qué error regresa si no se ejecuta.

Comment: El api me muestra en el navegador que se conecta y pone como que si se ejecutó pero dentro del mikrotik no veo que haga la ejecución del script.

Comment: esto es lo unico que me aparece al ejecutar routeros_api.php Connection attempt #1 to 192.168.17.135:8728... <<< [6] /login >>> [5/5] bytes read. >>> [5, 39]!done >>> [37/37] bytes read. >>> [37, 1]=ret=25ffaf8363f0be9feb08969d144b9a0a <<< [6] /login <<< [9] =name=api <<< [44] =response=006ceaeb849c8f9e0d60d6dc193db89def >>> [5/5] bytes read. >>> [5, 1]!done Connected... <<< [18] /system/script/run <<< [10] =.id=wlan7 Disconnected... Disconnected...

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en que el script que le estoy diciendo al api que escriba dentro del mikrotik esta incorrecto. Lo que quiero hacer es que me reinicie el dhcp de la interfaz osea /ip dhcp-client release 6 o simplemente que me ejecute el script que tengo dentro del mikrotik. Entonces este script que tengo creado dentro del mikrotik lo ejecuto de forma manual dentro del mikrotik usando el winbox ( system , script , run script 6) y me lo ejecuta perfectamente..entonces creo que el problema es que hay algun comando mal en el api